# Dynamic data exporting using R

Tags: r, loops, export-to-csv

```
mybrowser$navigate("http://bitcointicker.co/transactions/")
> a <- mybrowser$findElement(using = 'css selector',"#transactionscontainer")
> a
[1] "remoteDriver fields"
$remoteServerAddr
[1] "localhost"

$port
[1] 4444

$browserName
[1] "firefox"

$version
[1] ""

$platform
[1] "ANY"

$javascript
[1] TRUE

$autoClose
[1] FALSE

$nativeEvents
[1] TRUE

$extraCapabilities
list()

[1] "webElement fields"
$elementId
[1] "0"
```

I am trying to web scrape live Data using RSelenium and Rvest. I am planning to create a control loop with a timer to run every minute but I am struggling with the dynamic exporting of data into a folder on my computer. The ideal would be to create an output file and R would update rows automatically on the one file although I am not sure if this is possible using R.

Comment: Try `write.csv('output.csv', append = TRUE)`

Comment: thanks very much! I get another error now...                                                          > write.csv(a,file="output1.csv")
Error in as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE) : 
  cannot coerce class "structure("webElement", package = "RSelenium")" to a data.frame
> write.csv(a,file="output1.csv",append=TRUE)
Error in as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE) : 
  cannot coerce class "structure("webElement", package = "RSelenium")" to a data.frame
In addition: Warning message:
In write.csv(a, file = "output1.csv", append = TRUE) :
  attempt to set 'append' ignored

Comment: `write.csv` expects a `matrix` or `data.frame`.

Comment: Thanks! Is there anyway to convert the webElement into a data.frame?

Comment: The webElement represents, well, an element on the page. You probably don't want the element itself, but some text it contains. There's a `getElementText` method for this purpose.